# Get textarea Info Value LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

How get  value / info in LARAVEL?

admin.blade.php: https://pastebin.com/XHMM3PN9

GeneralController.php

```
$socket = $_POST['compr'];
```

ROUTE:

```
Route::post('sname', 'GeneralController@Sname')->middleware(['auth','admin:6']);
```

Comment: let me know if it works for you.```$socket = request()->compr; ```

Comment: Right now on clicking "Set Server Name" it's redirecting on url, not post compr. You have to use form to post that name in request. I've answered. Please check and let me know if it work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should be :

```
<form name="fname" action="{{ url('sname') }}" method="post">
   <legend>Server Name</legend>
   <textarea name="compr" rows="1" placeholder="Server Name" class="form-control">{{ old('compr') }}</textarea>
   <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" value="Set Server Name" />
</form>
```

Controller Method:

```
public function Sname(Request $request) {
   $socket = $request->compr;
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you would like to get input value from the request in your controller.

You can do this as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GeneralController extends Controller
{
    public function Sname(Request $request)
    {
        $compr = $request->input('compr');

        // do something with your input
    }
}
```